# Devcontainers: How to access git repository of parent directory in mounted child directory

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, containers, vscode-devcontainer

I have the following folder structure:

```
- .git
- services
  - service-a
    - .devcontainer
    - src
  - service-b
    - .devcontainer
    - src
  - service-c
    - .devcontainer
    - src
  - many more services...
```

I have the git repository defined in the root folder. I am using a VS-Code devcontainer for each service, in which I mount the child folders (`service-a/`, `service-b/`, `service-c/`). Inside of the container, I would like to use git commands, i.e. pull, add, commit, push, and so on.

This is not possible, because as soon as I mount a child folder into a container, it doesn't know that there is a .git folder in the root directory, because that one is not mounted in. Only the child folder is mounted in. VS-Code then thinks that it is not a git repository.

There are several solutions/workarounds to this problem that I know:

1. One solution is obviously to mount the whole root folder into the container, but my project is very large. I have dozens of services in this repository. Mounting only the respective service's folder gives me a better overview of its source code. Also, I have multiple Python projects with similar or the same module names. Hence, when using autocompletion in the container Python modules of other services are also found, which is not what I want.
2. Another solution is to tidy up and put each service into its own git repository. This is the solution I would favor, but sadly, I am not given time to do this.
3. Yet another workaround is to use a local console that runs on the host and not in the container. This gives me access to git. However, VS-Code will lose all its functionalities for git, because VS-Code doesn't know that the mounted folder is in fact a git repository.

Are there other solutions to this problem?

Comment: Putting the `.git` directory in a separate path in the container?

Comment: How do you mean? Would I mount the `.git` directory somewhere? Wouldn't git be confused why all of a sudden the files referenced in `.git` are located somewhere else? Maybe I'm missing some git fundamentals here.

Comment: I am just providing a _technical_ workaround, not caring about other factors. Just in case, inside the container, if you publish the `.git` directory somewhere, you can tell git where it is by providing `GIT_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: And this is hackish, anyway. Not saying it's a silver bullet.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @eftshift0. I tried to mount the .git folder into my container and adjust the devcontainer's `${localWorkspaceFolder}` so that it would lie in the correct path with respect to the original folder structure of the repository. I can now access git within the container. However, due to the other services' code not being mounted into the container, git thinks that these were deleted and shows the other services up as deleted when using `git status`. This is an issue on a different level, I think.

Comment: @Sebastian can you please add an answer with your solution to this issue? You seem to have solved it, at least partially, if I understand your last comment correctly.

Comment: @Adriaan, unfortunately I did not find a solution. As a hopefully temporary solution I am using git outside of my devcontainer. Though I still cannot use git tools within the container.

Comment: do you mount your `service-xx` directories one at a time ? a subset of them depending on your needs ? or all the directories under `services/` at once ?

Comment: if you code on one single service at a time, what behavior do you miss by doing the following: mounting the complete repo in the container, and telling vscode to open only `service-xx/` as a project directory ?

Comment: I have the same issue and still cannot find a proper solution.
It's interesting to see that VS Code can handle this well automatically in local setup, but doesn't work well with dev containers